# How to see what character is pressed with pynput python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

How can you see which button is pressed in pynput.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def a(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))
    if key == 'a':
        print('ape')

with Listener(on_press = a) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Does not see work.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
def a(key):
    print(f"{key}, was pressed")
    if key.char == "a":
        print("foo")


with Listener(on_press=a) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Output:

```
q'q', was pressed
w'w', was pressed
a'a', was pressed
foo
s's', was pressed
```

However this will cause issues if you press the caps lock for example so I would place in a try except block:

```
try:
    if key.char == 'a':
        print("foo")
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Comment: @sebastian, I have updated the answer. I think this is exactly what you want.